# Livewire multiple wire:click, first one works, rest do not

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am putting together a CRUD app using livewire and my issue is with wire:click on the different buttons. I have a create modal come up and the wire:click in that modal works perfectly. However the edit and delete buttons on the main page do not fire off when clicked.

The only way I can get the edit button to fire is if it is the only button with wire:click on the page.

These two buttons are inside a @foreach loop for each organization. This loop builds out the table

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" wire:target="edit('{{$org->id}}')">Edit</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" wire:click="delete({{$org->id}})">Delete</button>
```

How can I get these wire:clicks to fire off for each row in the table.

I do have @livewireScripts on my app layout

Answer (score 2):

To not confuse Livewire, you should use `wire:key` on elements in a loop. This also means that you should wrap you HTML in one parent `<div>`.

```html
@foreach ($items as $org)
    <div wire:key="org-{{ $org->id }}">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" wire:target="edit('{{$org->id}}')">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" wire:click="delete({{$org->id}})">Delete</button>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

- https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks a lot @Qirel, using wire:key works for me : ). I was using wire:loading while deleting elements from a list with a button in each record. But after click once of them, the rest of loading were showing in another row instead of the one I clicked. This solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Livewire uses a complex DOM diffing algorithm to intelligently swap components. So When you have loops make sure to add keys and wrap them in a parent container.

```
<div wire:key="{{$org->id}}">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" wire:target="edit('{{$org->id}}')">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" wire:click="delete({{$org->id}})">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the above and none worked, I found a yet simpler solution.
Wrap your `@foreach` inside a `<div>` like so;

```
<div>
@foreach ($items as $org)
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" wire:target="edit('{{$org->id}}')">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" wire:click="delete({{$org->id}})">Delete</button>
@endforeach
</div>
```