# why Dynamically add section doesn't work after retrieving the data from DB?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a button that adds a new language section to the form for the users to add a new language to their profile and it was working fine until I added that part which gets the existing user languages from DB to show in case they want to change the language or update it. I have been struggling for hours and can't figure out why is this happening why it stops working when the `getUserLanguages` function is being called. and when remove the `getUserLanguages` function from the `render` method it will start working again.

component controller:

```
public function addLanguage($i)
{
    $i = $this->i;
    if ($i <= 3)
    {
        $i = $i + 1;
        $this->i = $i;
        array_push($this->languages , ['language_name'=>'', 'language_level'=>'']);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->sweetAlert('error', 'You only can add 3 langauges.');
    }
}


public function getUserLanguages()
{
    if (empty(!UserLanguage::where('user_id', auth()->user())))
    {
        $this->languages = UserLanguage::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get(['language_name', 'language_level'])->toArray();
        $this->i = count($this->languages);
    }
}
```

the view:

```
@foreach ($languages as $index)
    <div class="card card-body mb-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="" for="languageName">Language</label>
                <select class="form-control form-control-alternative" name="language-name" {{-- id="languageName" --}} wire:model="languages.{{ $loop->index }}.language_name">
                    <option value="" class="form-control" selected disabled>Select Language</option>
                    @foreach ($language_names as $name)
                        <option value="{{ $name->abbreviation }}" class="form-control">{{ $name->language }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="" for="languageProficiency">Proficiency</label>
                <select class="form-control form-control-alternative" name="language-proficiency" {{-- id="languageProficiency" --}} wire:model="languages.{{ $loop->index }}.language_level">
                    <option value="" class="form-control" selected disabled>Proficinecy Level</option>
                    @foreach ($language_levels as $level)
                        <option value="{{ $level->level }}" class="form-control">{{ $level->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @error('languages.*.level')
        <small class="text-warning">{{ $message }}</small>
    @enderror
    @error('languages.*.language')
        <small class="text-warning">{{ $message }}</small>
    @enderror
@endforeach

@if (count($languages) < 3)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-round btn-block" wire:click="addLanguage({{$i}})"><span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Like I have mentioned in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64817742/livewire-multiple-wireclick-first-one-works-rest-do-not/64818051#64818051), you need to use `wire:key` when creating dynamic elements in a loop with Livewire.

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working"? What exactly is not working? What have you tried to debug why it is not working?

Comment: The add language section button doesn't add a new section anymore. but as soon as stop calling the function that gets the current user languages from the DB it starts working. I added the `wire:key` also but nothing changed. I used `dd` for every single line of code but what I realized is seems the `array_push` adds a new array to the array stack but it doesn't get rendered by the `render` method. when i `dd` the array there is an empty array added to the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally after i called the `getUserLanguages()` from the `mount` method instead of the `render` method everything works as it should be.